# How to export python project with virtual environment?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyinstaller

When we export python project (i.e. by converting to .exe file) how can we include the library we used, which are in virtual environment folder("venv") in the dictionary.

Comment: Normally the dlls for all required packages will be included with the distributable `.exe`. You don't need to worry about venv.

Comment: I don't think you need the entire virtual environment in your executable. Maybe you want all the dependencies be there. If that's the case, [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't Confuse between virtual Environment and the executable.

Simple explanation

Executable:

this is for packaging/freezing the code to exe and we can even run the exe in any machine without python also.

exe creation modules:

```
pyinstaller
py2exe
```

Virtualenv:

This is for maintaining packages and dependencies. if you are working on multiple python projects you can create multiple environments for managing all the packages independently and you can generate requirements.txt and share with a colleague so they can install project dependency in a single command

You can also generate exe for the project inside the virtualenv.

if you are not using virtualenv then your requirement file will have a lot of junk which you installed earlier for some other project also.

export method:

```
pip freeze requirements.txt     (Copy the generated file to another machine)
pip install -r requirements.txt (from another machine)
```